# Cannot hear audio file (solved)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I've been trying to use the Video Sequencer in Blender to use add audio. One time I tried it worked but now I cannot hear it anymore. What could be the reason that the audio isn't working?

Solved: The playback feature was on Mute

[image]

Comment: Check if you have enabled "Mute" in the _Playback_ menu of the _Timeline_.